# DataTime Picker. Исключение даты и времени

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся **встречи** для определенной комнаты.

Хочется, что бы при создании новой **встречи** в поле ( *с выбором даты и времени дата* ) и временные диапазоны,которые заняты, были некликабельны, т.е. их нельзя было выбрать.

Ну и желательно это все реализовать средствами DataTime Picker.

Answer (score 2):

Какого [DateTime Picker](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/)?
Для [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) есть [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) и [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate). [Демо](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max).

О том, как запретить определенные даты/диапазоны можно почитать где-то тут: [jQuery UI DatePicker Disable/Enable Specified Dates](http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/).
Пример оттуда же:

```
// Disable a list of dates
var disabledDays = ["9-21-2010", "9-24-2010", "9-27-2010", "9-28-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-17-2010", "9-2-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-4-2010", "9-5-2010"];
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays
});
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/yY4gZ/) для ленивых и недоверчивых.

Comment: Думаю, он имел ввиду  jQueryUI Datepicker.

Он видимо хочет, чтобы данные брались из таблицы, т.е. базы, а там может быть несколько дат, а потом эти даты disabled в календаре. По крайней мере меня моя формулировка больше устраивает, т.к. тоже оч. волнует :)

Comment: @MyNamels, как-то я потерял момент с запретом определенных дат. Обновил ответ.

Comment: а как вместо `var disabledDays = ["9-21-2010", "9-24-2010", "9-27-2010", "9-28-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-17-2010", "9-2-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-4-2010", "9-5-2010"];` сделать свою выборку из базы? В общих чертах.

Comment: @MyNamels, не обижайтесь, но в общих получится так:

 1. Получить даты из базы
 2. Передать их в JS

Comment: С датой я тоже недавно нашел пример, но вот как сделать тоже самое и для времени?